# Is it faster to load several small files, or one big file?

Tags: mysql

We have a 26GB file that we have to load into an empty table. I was curious, is it faster to load nine 3GB files or one 26GB file? Or is there no difference?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier for the storage engine to load in smaller chunks. The reason is that a big data load fills up the InnoDB rollback segment, and that takes time to purge.

For this reason, tools like [pt-fifo-split](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-fifo-split.html) exist. This helps to process a huge file in modestly-sized pieces, without copying the pieces to disk.